# Querying Partitioned Table in Lambda

Tags: postgresql, aws-lambda, amazon-athena, partitioned-view

I have one partitioned table 'table1' and I'm able to run select clause on this table in Athena and it gives result as well.

However, when I try to run the query on this Table 'table1' using Lambda Function, it gives me the following Error

```
'SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:8: SELECT * not allowed from relation that has no columns'
```

Below is the python script of Lambda

```
client = boto3.client('athena')

    #Setup and Perform query
    response = client.start_query_execution(
        QueryString = 'Select * FROM table1', 
        QueryExecutionContext = {
            'Database' : 'test'
        },
        ResultConfiguration = {
            'OutputLocation': 's3://test/'
        }
    )
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing the Catalog in your Query Execution Context

Comment: @Caldazar - Added Catalog in Query Execution and tried..but it didn't work

Comment: I was facing issue because of Lake Formation Permission, i gave permission for the table to the IAM Role I was using in Lambda then it worked!